# bit shifting in c# vs PHP

Tags: c#, php

I'm porting a class from C# to PHP. The part I'm having trouble with creates a hash of a string in C# by shifting bits repeatedly. The PHP code gives me the same output for the first few iterations but then starts producing wildly different results than the C# version. Assume the string I'm hashing is 'ddc74'.

Here's the C#:

```
uint hash = 0;

foreach (byte b in System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s))
{
      hash += b;
      hash += (hash << 10);
      hash ^= (hash >> 6);
}
```

And here's the PHP:

```
$hash = 0;
settype($hash, "integer");

// convert string to unicode array because the c# version uses each unicode byte.
$source = mb_convert_encoding($s, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
$source = unpack('C*', $source);
foreach ($source as $b)
{
    var_dump(array('getEightByteHash() b : ' => $b,));

    $hash += $b;
    $hash += ($hash << 10);
    $hash ^= ($hash >> 6);
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?  The PHP code goes off the rails in the 3rd iteration.

Comment: In php you are setting it s an integer, in c# its a uint (32 bit unsigned), maybe thats it? Since PHP doesn't support unsigned values, you may have to use a 64-bit integer, unless the PHP one is already 64-bit, its very platform dependent like C/C++ is.

Comment: You need to take the machine endianess into account when performing bit shifting or masking

Comment: I thought of the uint vs integer thing and also tried float on the PHP side with the same results.  As for the endianess, they are both Intel based machines.  The C# is running on 64-bit Windows and the PHP on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: I turns out that the PHP code failing when the $hash value exceeds the size of a 32-bit integer.  This is strange because the code is running on a 64-bit machine.  Apparently, PHP can't do bitwise operations on integers larger than 32-bit size.  Does anyone know how to get around this limitation?